# How should a LG 6600W1K001C Microwave Interlock Door Switch function?

Tags: electrical, appliances, microwave-oven

The LG microwave oven LMV1680BB stopped heating.  I checked out main components and all checked out fine.  I then checked the 3 door switches. Two of them (top and bottom switches) appear to be the same but the middle one is different. The top and bottom switches have continuity when the door is closed. But the middle switch has continuity all the time whether or not the door is closed. Is this the way it should function or should the middle switch should only have continuity when the door is open and no continuity when the door is closed?

Comment: Unless it changes state briefly mid-closing the door (**which I consider entirely possible given the tricks they use to circumvent bypassing the interlock system**) not changing state is probably a sign that it's not happy. If you have it to the point where you can manually actuate it, does it change state when you manually actuate it?

Comment: It's rare to be able to get precise detail on how these are set up, as they don't want them bypassed.